# How do I ensure PHPCS takes annotations into account?

Tags: php, drupal, namespaces, phpcs

PHPCS is reporting

`<error line="5" column="1" severity="warning" message="Unused use statement" source="Drupal.Classes.UnusedUseStatement.UnusedUse"/>`

for my use statement

`use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException;`

however later in the same file I have

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * @throws EntityStorageException
   */
  protected function setUp(): void {
```

so it seems to me that PHPCS is not checking the annotations when deciding if a namespace is unused?

BTW I'm using the config_set from https://www.drupal.org/project/coder so perhaps it's a bug there. I tried switching config checking off for that line using `// phpcs:disable` and `// phpcs: ignore` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation ([PHP_Codesniffer: ignoring parts of a file](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#ignoring-parts-of-a-file)):

You can try wrapping the offending code in special comments. Their example:

```
$xmlPackage = new XMLPackage;
// phpcs:disable
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
$xmlPackage->send();
// phpcs:enable
```

(Imperfect answer but at least it can let you get to a clean `phpcs` run.)